# Cannot use the right variables

Tags: php, mysql

Well, I have a login page where I enter username and password and login to ucp-home.php page. Here is the beginning of the ucp-home.php file:

```
    <?php include("sql.php");include("auth.php");
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","axylus","denismm1234");
mysql_query("SET NAMES UTF8");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("velto", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  $skin = $row['SkinID'];
  $igname = $row['Username'];
  $playerid = $row['UID'];
  $tls = $row['TLS'];
  $phonenumber = $row['Ph'];
  $fightingstyle = $row['FightingStyle'];
  $pastnames = $row['PastNames'];
  $staff = $row['Staff'];
  $staff2 = $row['Staff2'];
  $staff3 = $row['Staff3'];
  $staff4 = $row['Staff4'];
  $donor = $row['Donor'];
  $driving = $row['Driving'];
  $weapon = $row['Weapon'];
  $flying = $row['Flying'];
  };

mysql_close($con);
```

The problem is that it is using the data from the last row, not the row of the logged in username.

Here is my log.php file:

```
    <?php
    include("sql.php"); //Connect to SQL

    session_start(); //Start session for writing

    function Fix($str) { //Clean the fields
        $str = @trim($str);
        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
            $str = stripslashes($str);
        }
        return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
    }

    $errmsg = array(); //Array to store errors

    $errflag = false; //Error flag

    $username = Fix($_POST['username']); //Username
    $password = Fix($_POST['password']); //Password

    //Check Username

    //Check Password


    //If there are input validations, redirect back to the registration form
    if($errflag) {
        $_SESSION['ERRMSG'] = $errmsg;
        session_write_close();
        header("location: index.php");
        exit();
    }

    //Create SELECT query
    $qry = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `Username` = '$username' AND `Password` = '" . md5($password) . "'";
    $result = mysql_query($qry);

    //Check whether the query was successful or not
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $_SESSION['UID'] = $row['UID'];
            $_SESSION['USERNAME'] = $username;
            if($_SESSION['Full Name'] = $_SESSION['Full Name']) echo "Success";
            session_write_close();
            header("location: dashboard.php");
        }
    } else {
        $_SESSION['ERRMSG'] = "Invalid username or password";
        session_write_close();
        header("location: index-invalid.php");
        exit();
    }
?>
```

I hope you understood what exactly is my problem. Thank you in advance.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: do you want the details of the currently logged in user in uc-home.php?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While using login scripts, you have to write the details of the current session into the session array.So in your log.php,do this (or use a similar key like a time+username hash)

```
session_start();
...
//if user is authenticated
$_SESSION['user'] = $username;
```

And in your ucp-home.php use this:

```
...
session_start();
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username='$_SESSION[user]'");
...
```